# Autopopulateregionbehaviour + MEF

Tags: prism, mef

I am writing a new application which registers views within regions automatically using the PRISM AutoPopulateRegionBehaviour. This works fine when I register the views at app startup, however I am trying to use the MEF DeploymentCatalog to download a new XAP and update the region however this doesn't appear to be working (no views are displayed) and setting a breakpoint in the region behaviour. I'll try and upload a small snippet later but I wanted to pre-empt whether this should be possible or whether I need to call something to force the regions to refresh.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted. The problem was that the RegisteredViews Import wasn't being satisfied, the reason for this was that I was importing the viewmodel by interface type rather than by concrete type i.e.

I renamed:

[Import]
        public IABCViewModel ViewModel
        {
            set
            {
                this.DataContext = value;
            }
        }

to:

```
   public ABCViewModel ViewModel
    {
        set
        {
            this.DataContext = value;
        }
    }
```

I think this is because I need to register a type mapping for the interface to the concrete type (though this wasnt necessary in WPF).